# 2017 MacBook Pro kernel panics when it sleeps after update to Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, catalina, kernel-panic

After I update to Catalina (10.15.2), the system will freeze when I plug the USB keyboard to the Macbook.

I ran the Hardware check, but there is no thing broken and I also had tried  to rest the SMC. That does not work for me too.

However, This kernel panic happened in the last night, I just closed the MacBook and did not plug any extra device to the MacBook. And similar kernel panic had happened about 3 times.

**Here is my System Info**:
[image]
**Here is crash report:**

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80194a295c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while entering darkwake on way to sleep. Suspected bundle: __kernel__. Thread 0x855.
Failure code:: 0x8531fb26 00000031

Backtracing specified thread
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff820b653900 : 0xffffff8018e60088 
0xffffff9240f5bab0 : 0xffffff8018d5d6f1 
0xffffff9240f5bb20 : 0xffffff8018d5beef 
0xffffff9240f5bb70 : 0xffffff8018d1daf1 
0xffffff9240f5bbb0 : 0xffffff8018d427cb 
0xffffff9240f5bc00 : 0xffffff8019485317 
0xffffff9240f5bc60 : 0xffffff8019484f2a 
0xffffff9240f5bcb0 : 0xffffff80193f73c2 
0xffffff9240f5bdc0 : 0xffffff80194815bd 
0xffffff9240f5be00 : 0xffffff801942757b 
0xffffff9240f5bea0 : 0xffffff8019426f74 
0xffffff9240f5bec0 : 0xffffff8018d7d765 
0xffffff9240f5bf40 : 0xffffff8018d7d291 
0xffffff9240f5bfa0 : 0xffffff8018ce213e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19C57

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C3E7E405-C692-356B-88D3-C30041FD1E72
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018b00000
System model name: MacBookPro14,3 (Mac-551B86E5744E2388)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3940624478490
last loaded kext at 2214624787114: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice  1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9dfd7000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 3741057768333: >!UAudio   320.49 (addr 0xffffff7f9df6d000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport 4.2
com.kairos.driver.DuetDisplay   1
com.valvesoftware.SteamInput    4357.73.42
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>AGPM   111.4.1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AHIDALSService    1
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.4
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.4
>!AHDA  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.4
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f4
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.5.21
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.3
@kext.AMD9500!C 3.0.4
>!AEmbeddedOSSupportHost    1
>SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.3
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!AMuxControl   4.5.21
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.422
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3420.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.61.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.4
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f4
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f4
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.4
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
|IONDRVSupport  569.3
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   569.3
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UiBridge  1.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AActuatorDriver   3420.2
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3420.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f4
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f4
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f4
>!AMultitouchDriver 3420.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   58
>!AHSSPISupport 58
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.7
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

***If you need extra information to solve the problem, Please leave the comment.***

Comment: Did you try NVRAM reset ? You mentioned only about SMC. You should do NVRAM reset to get rid of it.

Comment: @Udhy Last night, I rested my NVRAM and my Macbook didn't kernel panic again.

Comment: I will update the answer accordingly. Would you be kind to accept it if my suggestion helped?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to reset NVRAM of your device.

This chip stores information on screen resolution and can often become corrupted. You can reset it by starting your Mac while holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> . You should hear the Mac chime, restart and chime a second time. Then you can release the keys you are holding. More info [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).